# EXCEL - Open all links in a new tab

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel-sheet which contains many links.
How do I open them all at once in a new tab with my default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? Included checking url is valid (basic check). The advantage here is you adapt to log information about the response from the URL.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim h As Hyperlink

    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks

       If UrlOK(h.Address) Then h.Follow

     Next h

End Sub



Public Function UrlOK(ByVal url As String) As Boolean

    Dim request As Object
    Dim respCode As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      respCode = .Status
    End With

    If respCode = 200 Then UrlOK = True

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

**Edit:** Thanks to @Omegastripes for noting

**1)** If you use [`MSXML2.XMLHTTP` over `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.`1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227298(v=vs.85).aspx) you get a more reliable result

Benefits include (amongst others):

A) Simplified code to open a URL.

B) Separate sessions do not impact each other.

C) Protected Mode IE Support

D) Credential Cache

**2)** Use `HEAD` over `GET`, in the request, to reduce network traffic

With a [HEAD](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html) request, a server will only return the headers of a resource, rather than the resource itself.

So you could use a revised, more efficient function, as follows:

```
Public Function UrlOK(ByVal url As String) As Boolean

    Dim request As Object
    Dim respCode As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With request
      .Open "HEAD", url, False
      .Send
      respCode = .Status
    End With

    If respCode = 200 Then UrlOK = True

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

**Image of code in a standard module and where to place cursor to execute Test sub.**

[image: Code and cursor placement for execution with F5]

Comment: You may use `HEAD` instead of `GET` to avoid excessive traffic. Also `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` would give more reliable result, since it uses [WinINet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh227298(v=vs.85).aspx) as well as IE, but `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` uses WinHTTP stack.

Comment: I don't understand why the complicated code. On Error does the trick much simpler.

Comment: This is just a different way of doing things. Sometimes it is useful to log what the response is and it is a common next question about what to do with invalid URLs. Future readers get to see different ways of handling the situation.

Comment: This is not showing up under the macros. When I try to execute it in the VBA window it asks me  to choose a macro, but this one isnt under the list again.

Comment: Have you added a standard module?  With the Sub Test and the Function in it? You then press F5 to run the Test sub which makes the function call.

Comment: Do you have the developer tab in the ribbon showing? And are you familiar with running code from the visual basic editor (VBE)? Alt + F11 opens the VBE. Right click add module in project explorer, paste code in there. With the cursor inside the text for the Sub Test then press F5.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty easy in VBA

```
Sub OpenAll()
    Dim H As Hyperlink

    For Each H In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Hyperlinks
        H.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

If there are invalid URLs you can stop the code from erroring like this:

```
Sub OpenAll()
    Dim H As Hyperlink

    For Each H In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        On Error Resume Next
        H.Follow
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks is a bit shorter and works too.

Comment: For some reason nothing happens when I try to execute the macro :/