# Opening a hyperlink in a new tab of IE

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I have an Excel tool that generates links to intranet website. Is it possible to open hyperlinks in Internet Explorer in a next tab instead of new window? Only IE is an option as it's the company equipment with little user rights.

Comment: What sort of Link?  Is this a button in a UserForm (using VBA to open the link), or a Hyperlink in the Worksheet?

Comment: Its a hyperlink function in an Excel cell. =Hyperlink("https path")

Answer (score 0):

Reference Link:

[excel-open-all-links-in-a-new-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587897/excel-open-all-links-in-a-new-tab)

You need to use Follow keyword

```
Sub OpenAll()
    Dim H As Hyperlink

    For Each H In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Hyperlinks
        H.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently changing internet options in IE did the trick.

Comment: You could explain more about what options you use and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.